# A function with certain shape

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to simulate a certain type of condition with a **continuous** and **twice differentiable** function $f(x)$ that has the following shape:

1. The limit of $f(x)$ at $-\infty$ is finite but less or equal to zero, i.e.
   $$ -\infty < \lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x) \leq 0$$
2. There exists a unique point $y \in \mathbb{R}$  such that $f(x)$ is decreasing on $(-\infty,y)$ and increasing on $(y,\infty)$.
3. The limit at $\infty$ is positive or infinity i.e. $$0<\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \leq \infty.$$

However I'm struggling to find a good example of such a function that is simple enough to make the point clear. In other words I'm looking for a explicit examples of a function with the properties that I described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one that will work:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}-e^{-x^2},\;&x<0 \\ 1-2e^{-x^2/2},\;&x\ge 0. \end{cases}$$
Here's a plot:

[image]

Here's another that might work (inspired by David G. Stork's answer):
$$f(x)=\operatorname{tanh}(x)-e^{-x^2/4}.$$
Plot:

[image]

The thing is, I haven't double-checked that this function is monotonically decreasing before some $x,$ and monotonically increasing after.

Comment: Great! Does anything come to your mid that is not piecewise defined? It's not really an issue but more examples are welcome.

Comment: My guess is that David G. Stork's answer could be massaged to be correct. The $\operatorname{tanh}$ or $\arctan$ functions would be useful here, but they'd have to be modified to get the local minimum your conditions require.

Comment: Yes I tried to plot a bit different versions of his answers but I didn't manage to get one that I was looking for yet.

Comment: I've added another possibility, inspired by Stork's answer. Don't know if it's correct, but it looks good!

Comment: I plotted it's derivative and it seems that it has a unique zero.

Answer (score 1):

How about $(\tanh (x) + 1) + {e^{-x^2/2} \over \sqrt{2 \pi}}$?

[image]

Comment: That isn't decreasing on some interval $(-\infty, y)$. Also it's nowhere negative as the function clearly must be.

Comment: It seems that the picture isn't even the same function you have drawn?

Comment: @Kplusn:  Ooops... inserted the missing "+" sign.

Answer (score 1):

Here's mine
$$
f(x) = \frac{e^x(e^{2x}-1)}{e^{2x}+1}
$$
[image: picture]